# Hiding and unhiding a Collection in the Viewport

Tags: python, scripting, collections

This may have been asked before, but I cannot make sense of it. I need a script which simply toggles the eye of my collection named "Animation".
I have enabled my viewport by using `bpy.data.collections["Animation"].hide_viewport = False`
The eye however is closed and I need to open it with a script. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accessing collection from view layer?

```
bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children["Collection Name"].hide_viewport = False
```